# multiplying columns with missing values in them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new column by multiplying column A and B. The problem is that the column has some missing values in them.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [1,2,"",4],
    "B": [2.0,5.0,6.0,7.0]
})
df["C"] = df["A"].astype(float) * df["B"]
print(df)
```

I've looked into possible solutions and they c\all mention filling those values with 0s or 1s which I cannot do... Anyone have any ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: depending on the requirement you can replace the empty string value to 1 or 0 like: `df["C"] = df["A"].replace('','0').astype(float) * df["B"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about np.nan?

```
import numpy as np
df.replace("", np.nan,inplace=True)
df["C"] = df["A"].astype(float) * df["B"]

Out[100]: 
    A    B     C
0  1.0  2.0   2.0
1  2.0  5.0  10.0
2  NaN  6.0   NaN
3  4.0  7.0  28.0y
```

Comment: Just tested and it seems to be working. How does it differ from fillna?

Comment: "" is str type, it could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''.eg:  str + int
numpy.nan is IEEE 754 floating point representation of Not a Number (NaN). It's the traditional missing value marker of numpy.